# How to center image vertically?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am looking for a way to center the image vertically, something that is similar to `text-align center`. `text-align` center is kinda efficient since you don't need to specify the width of the parent or the width of the children, it will automatically center its content. Is there any other way to do something like this for positioning image vertically?

Comment: You can always use `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Google `css vertical center image` has 148 million results, and you didn't try 1 of them?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-align-an-image-vertically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways

Way 1 (*Preferred*), by using `display: table-cell`

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CnM27/)

---

Way 2, Using `position: absolute;` and `top: 50%` and than deduct 1/2 of the total `height` of the image using `margin-top`

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
}

div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -24px; /* half of total height of image */
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/CnM27/1/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Also see [Absolute Centering](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt) would be useful to add to the answer.

Comment: @hitautodestruct Not necessarily, but anyways I've added *preferred* there :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Also see [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown) by chris coyer

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in a parent div id parentDiv .. set image on background

```
#parentDiv
{
background:url(image.png) no-repeat center center;
height:500px;
width:500px;
}
```

or in child div do this thing...

```
position:absolute;
   top:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

All in the middle ...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="img"></div>
</div>

#container {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#040;
}
#container #img {
    background: url("url_to_image.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/PD6J4/

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've got works for old browsers but in the near future (right now has like the 70% of the browser support) you can do this, a much simpler and elegant solution:

```
.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@supports(object-fit: cover){
    .container img{
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center center;
    }
}
```